# Nuxt.js multiple external API calls with axios proxy

Tags: proxy, axios, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using multiple external APIs with Nuxt.js and axios, bet I have problems with SSR. When requests are coming from client-side this config is working and proxy is changing url, bet when requests are coming from server (on app page reload) proxy not hitting and axios using baseURL, which is one for all requests.

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
  axios: {
    proxy: true
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: process.env.FIRST_API_URL,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api/': ''
      }
    },
    '/api2/': {
      target: process.env.SECOND_API_URL,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api2/': ''
      }
    }
  },
```

Api call in one of Vuex store actions as example:

```js
export const actions: ActionTree<CoreState, RootState> = {
  async fetchItems ({ commit }) {
    await this.$axios.$get('/api2/items').then((response) => {
      commit('SET_ITEMS', response.data)
    })
  }
}
```

Action is dispatching from component asyncData method:

```js
async asyncData ({ store }) {
  await store.dispatch('items/fetchItems')
}
```

How to make this work both from client-side and server-side ?

Comment: Where do you make this `axios` call exactly? Are you using `nuxtServerInit`? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action

Comment: Core data are loaded using nuxtServerInit, but than each component is requesting more data by dispatching action with API call from appropriate store. Added more info about this to question.